# getting error from GSM modem after certain time

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command, ussd, gsmcomm

I have a GSM modem and send ussd command to it and wait for a response from that.
all operation are correct when GSM modem response in lower than 5 second. but when the response is higher than 5 second i received `+cusd:4` error from modem. any  idea for that?(`Modem is D-Link DWM-156 3G HSUPA USB Adapter`)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the timestamp in your connection to the modem (on C#).
I don't know how you establish your connection but I had the same problem in Python... changed the timestamp and it worked just fine.

Good luck